# Computer disconnects from WiFi and doesn't reconnect automatically

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, iwlwifi

I'm running Ubuntu Desktop 19.10 and mostly use it as a server. Periodically (every few days) it drops off wifi and doesn't reconnect. Rebooting wi-fi AP doesn't help. Only manual reconnect/suspend&resume/reboot of the ubuntu works.

None other device in my home has the same problem. How do I fix it so that it reconnects back automatically?

This is what I have in my journal at the time wi-fi drops:

```
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell avahi-daemon[1858]: Interface wlp3s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell NetworkManager[1857]: <info>  [1575922784.2641] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell avahi-daemon[1858]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.86.84.
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell NetworkManager[1857]: <info>  [1575922784.2637] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell avahi-daemon[1858]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.86.84 on wlp3s0.
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell NetworkManager[1857]: <warn>  [1575922784.2637] device (wlp3s0): no secrets: No agents were available for this request.
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell avahi-daemon[1858]: Interface wlp3s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell NetworkManager[1857]: <info>  [1575922784.2609] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: 4-way handshake -> disconnected
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell avahi-daemon[1858]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::d624:4b28:c9fa:65e4.
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell NetworkManager[1857]: <info>  [1575922784.2589] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell avahi-daemon[1858]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::d624:4b28:c9fa:65e4 on wlp3s0.
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell sh[2118]: sendto: Network is unreachable
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell NetworkManager[1857]: <info>  [1575922784.2569] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed bound -> done
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell dbus-daemon[1855]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.15' (
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell whoopsie[2094]: [12:19:44] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell whoopsie[2094]: [12:19:44] offline
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell sh[2118]: sendto: Network is unreachable
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell NetworkManager[1857]: <info>  [1575922784.2569] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell NetworkManager[1857]: <info>  [1575922784.2568] device (wlp3s0): state change: activated -> need-auth (reason 'supplicant-disconnect', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell NetworkManager[1857]: <info>  [1575922784.2566] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) disconnected during association, asking for new key
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell NetworkManager[1857]: <info>  [1575922784.2544] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> disconnected
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell wpa_supplicant[1856]: dbus: wpa_dbus_property_changed: no property SessionLength in object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell wpa_supplicant[1856]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="NSA Surveillance Van" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=WRONG_KEY
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell NetworkManager[1857]: <warn>  [1575922784.2259] sup-iface[0x55bd46b33930,wlp3s0]: connection disconnected (reason 2)
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell wpa_supplicant[1856]: wlp3s0: WPA: 4-Way Handshake failed - pre-shared key may be incorrect
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell wpa_supplicant[1856]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=70:3a:cb:00:60:b1 reason=2
Dec 09 12:19:44 dell kernel: wlp3s0: deauthenticated from 70:3a:cb:00:60:b1 (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
```

My wi-fi card:

```
  *-network                                                                                                                                                                                   
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3165         
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0       
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0           
       version: 79                                                                                                                                                                            
       serial: 70:1c:e7:24:02:48
       width: 64 bits                 
       clock: 33MHz  
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-23-generic firmware=29.1654887522.0 ip=192.168.86.84 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:140 memory:df700000-df701fff
```

Comment: What kind of wifi card do you have?

Comment: Intel. Updated the question with lshw output

Comment: Well, there are a couple of fixes I found. One, you can try setting the 802.11 to disable wireless-n by running the following command: `echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` Another fix involves changing your settings to set the password to share will all users in your network-manager settings if you are using network-manager.

Comment: my network manager already has "Available to all users" checkbox set (verified with nmtui). I will give disabling 11n a try

Comment: Also, is it possible that someone else is also using the nsa surveillance van SSID? Please follow the instructions [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/167115) and then please post a link to the output or the file as described in the answer. This will help other users that can answer this question by providing all relevant information about your hardware and neighboring networks, etc. Thanks!

Comment: Also, even if that works, the wifi-script will be able to identify a permanent solution by telling us *why* disabling wireless-n works. Personally, I am not a fan of disabling wireless-n. It could be a crowded network or a weak signal and there is a fix for both of these issues. Also, I forgot that you need to reboot to apply the change above and you can also run the following command to revert the change if it doesn't work: `sudo sed -i 's/options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1//' /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.con` and then reboot.